# ajax request after jquery validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I try to make an ajax request after a successful form validation. If I delete the `,` after `url: 'loginprivate.php'` the php code works but the validation dont. If I add the `,` the validation works but the php code not. The redirection after successful ajax request dont work anyway. How can I make that working, maybe with `$(form).ajaxSubmit();` when yes where should I add this line?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                username: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2,
                    maxlength: 30
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 30
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'loginprivate.php',   //url where you want to post the stuff.
    data:{
        username: 'root',
        password: ''
    },
    success: function(res){
        //here you will get res as response from php page, either logged in or some error.
         window.location.href = "http://localhost/localcorps/main.php";
    }
});
                return false; // for demo
            }
        });
    });
```

**my php code:**

```
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
            $hostname='localhost';
            $username='root';
            $password='';

            unset($_POST['password']);
            $salt = ''; 
            for ($i = 0; $i < 22; $i++) { 
                    $salt .= substr('./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', mt_rand(0, 63), 1); 
            }
            $_POST['password'] = crypt($_POST['password'],'$2a$10$'.$salt);
            $new = 0;
            try {
                    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=search",$username,$password);
                    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
                    VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."','".$_POST["password"]."')";
                    if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
                            echo "New Record Inserted Successfully";
                    }
                    else{
                            echo "Data not successfully Inserted.";
                    }
                    $new = $dbh->lastInsertId();
                    $dbh = null;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            if ($new > 0) 
            {

                $t = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;
                setcookie("username", $_POST['username'], $t);
                setcookie("userid", $new , $t);
            } 
        else
            {

            }
    }
```

Comment: show the php code. Doesn't make sense not sending real values as data. Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network for more clues. Is status 500?

Comment: I edit my question ;)

Comment: Please check the answer below, add one more field in data. It will work

Comment: You `unset($_POST['password'])` and then try to access it again which will throw exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im your ajax add this

```
data:{
    username: 'root',
    password: '',
    submit: true,// add this line as you are checking in php file.
},
```

Comment: Thank you after this I searched any days, I accept your answer in 9 minutes. :)

Comment: Ya sure. Glad it helped you:)